# I am currently reading "Hands on Programming with R" and was asked to "deal" a deck of cards: deal(deck)

Tags: r

I am currently reading "Hands on Programming with R" and was asked to "deal" a deck of cards: deal(deck). I got an error back saying the function "deal" could not be found. I'm using RStudio 1.2.5042.

Comment: Is that because you haven't written the function yet? I believe the solution is in [Section 6.2 of that book online](https://rstudio-education.github.io/hopr/r-notation.html).

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write a function to deal a hand, and maybe a function to shuffle. First, create the deck.

```
deck <- setNames(merge(
    data.frame(c(2:10,"J","Q","K","A"), 1:13), 
               c('spades','hearts','clubs','diamonds')), c('face','value','suit'))
```

And the functions.

```
shuffle <- function(deck) {
  deck[sample(nrow(deck)),]
}

deal <- function(deck, cards=5, cheat=FALSE) {
  if(cards<1) stop("Minimum of 1 card")
  deck <- shuffle(deck)
  if(cheat)
    if(cards==5)
      hand <- deck[deck$suit=="spades" & deck$value>=9,]
    else
      hand <- deck[deck$face=="A",][1:cards,]
  else
    hand <- deck[1:cards,]
  hand <- hand[order(hand$value),-2]
  rownames(hand) <- NULL
  hand
}
```

And test it.

```
deal(deck)
#  face   suit
#1    8 spades
#2   10  clubs
#3    J hearts
#4    J  clubs
#5    Q spades

deal(deck, cheat=TRUE)
#   face   suit
#9    10 spades
#10    J spades
#11    Q spades
#12    K spades
#13    A spades

deal(deck, cheat=TRUE, cards=4)
#  face     suit
#1    A diamonds
#2    A   hearts
#3    A    clubs
#4    A   spades
```

This is for one player only.